# A logarithimic simplification

Tags: logarithms

How could I simplify this? It must give $\dfrac{9}{2}+\ln (2)$.

$$\left( \dfrac{4}{2}+6+\ln (2)\right) - \left( \dfrac{1}{2}+3+\ln (1)\right) =8+\ln (2)-\dfrac{7}{2}-\ln (1)=\dfrac{9}{2}+\ln (2)-\ln (1)$$

Comment: note: $\ln(1)=0$.

Comment: You can also use the well-known identity $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(a/b)$ with $a=2$ and $b=1$, in case for some reason you do not remember that $\ln(1)=0$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have $$8-\frac{7}{2}+\ln(2)-\ln(1)=\frac{16-7}{2}+\ln(2)$$ since $$\ln(1)=0$$